# Android GPS Tracker is not disabled

Tags: android, gps, tracker

Here I am facing an issue with GPS in android.

In my code I am just displaying a marker on the map based on the current location, and its working fine.

When i call this code **GPS Tracker Engine Symbol is coming at the top of the screen.
And in the onPause() method I am calling myLocManager.removeUpdates(this)** ,but even I am out of that activity **that GPS Tracker is not disabled..*
Which become a big headache for me because it consuming more battery even app is in Sleep mode.

I am using  MyItemizedOverlay to draw the marker when location updated.

Can any one please help me how to solve this..?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `MyLocationOverlay` to display your current location?

`MyLocationOverlay` handles location updates on its own, i.e. it uses GPS. Call `.disableMyLocation()` to stop location updates.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.No I am using MyItemizedOverlay.How can I disable my location in this case.